# Retrieve distinct and recent values from the SQL table

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

I have a table like below.

[image]

I need to fetch the most recent records(for given time) for each unit from the above table. Each unit should have all the possible vehicle IDs but should not have duplicate vehicle IDs for the same unit.

**The output should be like this(all column names should be there).**

[image]

I have tried this query but it returns only a single record for each unit.

```
SELECT cv.UnitID, cv.timestamp, cv.bytes, cv.schema_version, cv.VehicleID
FROM ChannelValue cv WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(c.timestamp)
                   FROM ChannelValue c WITH (NOLOCK)
                   WHERE c.timestamp > '2023-05-09 12:11:41.596'
                     AND c.UnitID=cv.UnitID
                   GROUP BY c.UnitID)
ORDER BY cv.timestamp
```

The output of this query.
[image]

So, would appreciate if someone could help me do this with an optimized query.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server; please only tag the product you are *really* using.

Comment: 1) No need for the GROUP BY in the subquery.

Comment: 2) Use a window function to identify the most recent _row_.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

After doing many investigations was able to find a solution.
This query will resolve the problem.

Just replaced

```
c.UnitID=cv.UnitID GROUP BY c.UnitID
```

From

```
c.VehicleID=cv.VehicleID
```

Full query

```
SELECT cv.UnitID, cv.timestamp, cv.bytes, cv.schema_version, cv.VehicleID FROM ChannelValue cv WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE timestamp >= (SELECT MAX(c.timestamp) FROM ChannelValue c WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE c.timestamp > '2023-05-09 12:11:41.596' AND 
c.VehicleID=cv.VehicleID) ORDER BY cv.timestamp
```